# Install xgboost under python with 64-bit msys failing

Tags: python-2.7, msysgit, msys, msys2, xgboost

I want to install xgboost using anaconda python. In this process, I am trying to install xgboost. While trying to "make" the xgboost i am getting the below error:

```
C:\GitRepository\xgboost>


g++ -m64 -c -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -fopenmp -fPIC
 -o updater.o src/tree/updater.cpp
src/tree/updater.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is positio
n independent)
 // Copyright 2014 by Contributors
 ^
src/tree/updater.cpp:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
make: *** [updater.o] Error 1
```

I understood from the other Stack overflow posts that 32 bit gcc cannot go with the 64bit anaconda that i am using. However when i installed mingw-w64 i could see that it has g++ only for mingw32 and not for mingw-w64. Under the mingw-w64 package, g++ and other applications+folders are present only for mingw32 and not for 64. For mingw-64 only a batch file and a internet short cut is present.

Could you please guide me what is going wrong or guide me to an appropriate place from where i can download for mingw-64.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really using [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/), then you should not be downloading separate compilers.  You should install 64-bit g++ using MSYS2's package manager, by running `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`.  Then make sure that you start the MSYS2 shell using the shortcut that is named something like "MSYS2 Win64 Shell" in your start menu.  Type `which g++` in Bash and make sure it outputs `/mingw64/bin/g++`.  Then you should be able to compile code for 64-bit Windows.

I'm not sure that this answer is complete.  If you need more help with MSYS2, it would be good to post the exact commands you are running to download/extract the source code and build so that others can reproduce the error.

Comment: Thank you. I will try as suggested and get back to ou.