# Fail when building xgboost using 64-bit mingw g++

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, mingw-w64, xgboost

I would like to compile xgboost for Anaconda Python 3.x in 64-bit Windows 10, so I followed the steps here - https://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/build.html#building-on-windows and here - [Install xgboost under python with 64-bit msys failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33454285/install-xgboost-under-python-with-64-bit-msys-failing). Using the 64-bit mingw g++, I got the following error message when "make -j4" using mingw64.mk:

```
g++: error: dmlc-core/libdmlc.a: No such file or directory
g++: error: rabit/lib/librabit_empty.a: No such file or directory
Makefile:120: recipe for target 'lib/libxgboost.dll' failed
mingw32-make: *** [lib/libxgboost.dll] Error 1
```

Can you please let me know what's going on and how I can resolve this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first go to the dmlc-core and rabit sub directories and execute make there. Then come to the xgboost library and execute build.sh.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were not in the right folder when running install. Try the following.

Pull up Anaconda prompt, run:

```
cd xgboost\python-package  
python setup.py install
```

If this still fails, try [the process in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36872334/4896087) from scratch and it should work. Quote from the link:

> First follow the official guide with the following procedure (in Git
>   Bash on Windows):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

> then install TDM-GCC here and do the following in Git Bash:

```
alias make='mingw32-make'
cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk; make -j4
```

> Last, do the following using anaconda prompt or Git Bash:

```
cd xgboost\python-package  
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing those libraries in your directory. You have to clone xgboost recursively to include them as well. Just follow the clone process as mentioned in the installation guide and you should be fine!